# Dynamically editing HTML fields through javascript using table data in MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, dynamic, editing

I'm having issues trying to figure out how to dynamically populate form fields using database fields.  The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<form id="notes" name="notes" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table width="700" border="0.5" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" style="text-align:center">
        <select name="noteselect" id="noteselect" onchange="<?php ?>">
            <option value="new">
                Add new...
            </option>
            <?php
                if(isset($_COOKIE['deceasedID']))
                {
                    $SqlStatement = "SELECT PK_Notes, Note_Title, Date_Entered FROM Notes WHERE FK_Deceased = '".$_COOKIE['deceasedID']."'";

                    $res = ExecuteSQL($SqlStatement, true);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        echo "<option value='".$row['PK_Notes']."'>".$row['Note_Title']." - ".$row['Date_Entered']."</option>";
                    }
                    $error = " ";
                }
```

In this snippet, the ExecuteSQL function runs the mysqli_connect/query/close functions and then returns a result set

What I'd like to do is to use the onchange event for the select tag to run a php script that runs a mysqli function that populates the fields with the data.  I think I'd have to use javascript to dynamically edit the field's innerHTML with the data from the result set, but how do I embed the javascript into the php function?  I've tried doing the following, keep in mind, the $SqlStatement variable contains the sql statement, and the statement does work, I've run it directly on the db and it works:

```
$res = ExecuteSQL($SqlStatement, true)
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById(*fieldname*).value = $row['db_row_name']</script>
```

Yet this does nothing, so I don't know whats wrong here.  Is it not possible to use a php function to run javascript and dynamically update fields?  Or would it be better to just use 100% javascript to do this and run any sql through embedded php in the javascript?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PHP script is executed on the server. Javascript is executed on the client. They are not executed at the same moment at all. If you want to do some stuff after choosing a value in a select, you have to use AJAX call. When the user choose an option, Javascript send an AJAX call to your server (to a new script) and then when the script generate the JSON response (in example), on the client side, the JS is handling the response and modify the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to provide a sample here to solve this type of problem.

This will give an idea of how AJAX will be used to populate dynamic content from PHP.

** HTML file **
    
        
            
            
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#select1').change(function() {

```
                    //Get current item's value
                    var select1 = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "getOptions.php?select1=" + select1,
                        success : function(data) {
                            var result, opts = "";

                            //We get comma separated data
                            result = data.split(',');
                            //Prepare options
                            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                opts += "<option value='" + result[i] + "'>" + result[i] + "</option>";
                            }
                            //Populate second select
                            $('#select2').html(opts);
                        },
                        error : function() {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                });

                //By default populate options for currently selected item
                $('#select1').trigger('change');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p>
                Select 1
                <select id='select1'>
                    <option  value="1">1</option>
                    <option  value="2">2</option>
                    <option  value="3">3</option>
                    <option  value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                Select 2
                <select id='select2'>
                </select>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

** PHP File (getOptions.php) **

```
<?php
    $select1 = $_GET['select1'];
    $result = "";

    /*
        Here fetch data and return to front-end
    */

    //following is used to generate some dummy code.

    for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
        if($result != "") $result .= ",";
        $result .= $select1.$i;
    }
    echo $result;
?>
```

I am just sending comma separated values from back-end. You can try JSON.

Also I am sending some dummy code from back-end. You can use your DB to fetch results and send to front-end.